# Heat map with Bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, heatmap

I need to write a data visualization in Python of the type you see in the image using [Bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/index.html#)

[image: heat map]

Basically what I need to do is:
(1) Plot a heat map of my data
(2) Plot the cross section along a vertical and horizontal line, plotting it in a separate window

Can you give me any suggestion abut where to start?

Comment: Which tool produced the diagram that you use here for illustration?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov The software Labber https://www.keysight.com/us/en/products/software/application-sw/labber-software.html